# Iphone device playing video in AWS server returns error "The Server is not correctly configured."

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have to play a video on my EC2 server (Amazon server), the streaming is working correctly on Android and browser, but on iPhone device it returns error "**The Server is not correctly configured.**", while the same video is working correctly on iPhone when I try it on another server inside my network.

any help what is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please check your server support "Range Requests"?

Comment: Yes, it's supported, but the problem was from the firewall, I have to enable the http release from the settings/web/advance settings. And it's working now very well